# Write to the same row at the same time without locking?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I need to do is to write to the **same row from two different sources** (procedures/methods/services).

The first call that comes in creates the row, and the next one just updates it.

This needs to happen without any locking taking place. And if possible I would like to be able to call either source **just once** (not repeatedly by dealing with locking errors)

Here is kinda what I have now in a third procedure that the others call and just inserts a row (only inserts into the xyz) or returns true if there is a row.
That way it´s just fast and unlikely that both calls arrive at the same time.

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Wait] WHERE xyx= @xyz)
    BEGIN
           -- The row exists because the other datasource
           -- has allready inserted a row with the same xyz  
           --  UPDATE THE ROW WITH DATA COMING IN    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
           -- No row with value xyz exists so we INSERT it with
           -- the extra data.
    END
```

I know it does´t guaranty no lock. But in my case it´s actually unlikely that both arrive at the same time and even if they would it´s user controlled so they will get an error and will just try again. BUT I wan´t to solve this.

I have been seeing [Row Versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx) popping up but I´m not sure if that helps or how I should use it.

[image: The problem in an image]

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that locking is some sort of horrible, bad thing that must be avoided at any cost, when it's actually the thing making concurrent updates possible in the first place, and very cheap if the lock is actually uncontested. If you remove (pessimistic) locking, you have to use optimistic, version-based updates, like you get with snapshot isolation -- but then you just trade waiting for retrying. It's one or the other, since an RDBMS has to treat updates atomically.

Comment: If you want the user to get no errors in this scenario, you need to actually *lock more*, either by using the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction level or with the `HOLDLOCK` hint on the `EXISTS`. If locking really becomes a hotspot, you can slightly optimize things by always doing the update, then doing the insert if the `@@ROWCOUNT` for the update returned no rows. This saves you an explicit check, which helps especially if updates are more frequent than inserts. In all cases, you need a transaction to ensure the statements happen as one (unless you use `MERGE`, which takes care of that internally).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Michael J Swarts' article [Mythbusting: Concurrent Update/Insert Solutions](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/). This will show you all possible do's and don'ts. Including the fact that merge actually *doesn't* do a great job in solving concurrency issues.